# polar coordinates equation for a rookie

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I'm entering uni in a couple of days and as always there are initiations. Mine is themed after Naruto and we have to create a costume respecting a buch of criteria. One of them is that we need a rasen shuriken that has to "follow the Minato form in polar coordinates". It is followed by the following equation :

$\mathbf{r}=1/2 * e^{(-7i\theta/5)}*(1+e^{(2i\theta/5)})*(-e^{(2i\theta/5)}+e^{(4i\theta/5)}-e^{(6i\theta/5)}+e^{(8i\theta/5)}-e^{(2i\theta)}+e^{(12i\theta/5)}+1)$

My problem is that I don't know how to visualize this equation with the tools I have and know. please help !

edit: fixed a mistake in the equation

Comment: So what are the tools you have and know, what are the tools you're allowed to use, and in what form do you need the end result?

Comment: @Magma I can basically use every since it is supposed to be fun and jovial (emphasis on supposed)

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It is supposed to look like a shuriken so i don't know what's up with that... maybe it is supposed tu appear in a graph of real vs imaginary ??? Plus I spotted a mistake in my equation so yeah...

Comment: Now that you've corrected it, the last term is a geometric progression, so you should try to simplify it.  Note that for this to make sense, you're going to have to get a real value on the right-hand side, because $r$ is real.

Comment: It simplifies to $r=\cos(7\theta/5)$.  It's very simple once you notice the geometric progression.